# Using OptaPlanner for VRPPD + Time Windows

Tags: java, optaplanner, vehicle-routing, jsprit

I'm attempting to switch from JSprit to OptaPlanner for our [Vehicle Routing Problem](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#vehicleRouting) with pickup & delivery + time windows. JSprit is giving sub-optimal results and the process to get there is opaque, and performance is becoming an issue (scheduling 1-2k trips in a batch).

I see a [discussion from 2018](https://issues.redhat.com/projects/PLANNER/issues/PLANNER-833?filter=allopenissues) discussing some of OptaPlanner's difficulties and performance issues surrounding heterogenous pickup & delivery, but it's not clear whether they've been resolved. Geoffrey has a link to [his GitHub repo](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/optaplanner-mixedvrp-experiment/blob/master/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/move/RideSwapMoveIteratorFactory.java) but it sounds more like a daring experiment than a best practice. I'm having trouble locating a good example of how others have modeled VRPPD + time windows.

The question, really, is: is it possible to model a VRPPD OptaPlanner problem that will perform well with thousands of trips and ~100 vehicles?

**Edit: a bit more about the routing problem**
These are passenger pickups and dropoffs, in any order (allowing double-ups in a vehicle). Typically covering a state-wide area.

Soft Costs:

- Extra passenger time in vehicle
- Driver per-day salary, overtime
- Fuel
- Passenger earlier/later than requested time
- Lunch breaks for drivers
- Preferred vehicle types by passenger

Hard Costs:

- Vehicle capacities (for ambulatory, wheelchair)
- Vehicle features (ramp van)
- Vehicle owner eligibility / billing rules
- Excessive time in vehicle
- Passenger arrives outside normal business hours
- Do-not-share-vehicle for passenger

Additional wrinkles

- Multi-leg trips, where a passenger is picked up at A, makes a 15-minute stop a B, then proceeds to C

I've been impressed by the documentation and performance I've seen in OptaPlanner so far. So I'm optimistic that this will work, but I wish there were more examples or best practices for time-windowed vehicle routing. Building a functional scheduler just to evaluate its feasibility is daunting.

Comment: Are you mixing pickups and deliveries? So for example can you: pick up A, pick up B, drop off B, pick up C, drop off A, drop off C?

Comment: Correct, mixes pickups with optional double-ups in any order.

Comment: Then I fear the best we have is that mixedvrp experiment repo - we haven't focussed yet on this use case and it doesn't "just work" as most use cases. That worked when I wrote it, and I know a company that has it in production, but it didn't work properly last time I tried my codebase. It still uses chained variables, but even with @PlanningListVariable you still need custom move factories to both change the pickup and the delivery of an item.

Comment: Good info! I'll work from your example. I'll take the warnings against using `InnerScoreDirector` with a grain of salt, since I'm not about to write my own implementation. Thanks!